# How to easily templatize math functions based on precision?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have two math functions that are already pre-defined:

```
float sqrtf(float a);
double sqrt(double a);
```

I have some templatized code that I'm writing in C++ that I'd like to switch automatically between the two:

```
template<typename Precision>
void foo(Precision arg) {
    sqrt<Precision>(arg); // Call into sqrtf or sqrt depending on type?
}
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish the above without having to manually rewrite all the overloads manually?

Edit for clarity: These are C and CUDA functions (eg. BLAS) which have no pre-built overloads.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to C++17's [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) it is as simple as

```
template <typename...>
struct always_false { static constexpr bool value = false; };  // used to make the static_asset value a dependent value otherwise it always fires

template<typename Precision>
void foo(Precision arg) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Precision, double>)
        sqrt(arg);
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Precision, float>)
        sqrtf(arg);
    else
        static_assert(always_false<Precision>::value, "foo can only be called with the types double or float");
}
```

If you can't use C++17 then you can specialize or overload `foo` for `double` and `float` and have those specializations/overloads call the correct function.

Comment: So the pain point is that I actually need to support 4 types: float, double, complex_float, complex_double

Comment: @proteneer You could make the function body a macro where you just specify the functions you want called.  It is a little hacky but I'd let it go for something like this.  Alternatively you would make a macro that builds the overload set for you.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are using [C functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/sqrt). If you use the [C++ functions](http://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/INF478/docs/Cpp/en/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt.html) instead (C++ has overloading) you dont need to play any tricks:

```
template<typename Precision>
void foo(Precision arg) {
   std::sqrt(arg); // Calls the right overload depending on type of arg
}
```

> So the pain point is that I actually need to support 4 types: float,
>   double, complex_float, complex_double

If you have to use the c functions then you can write a wrapper. Write one `sqrt` that dispaches to the right C function:

```
template <typename T>
T my_sqrt(T x);

template<>
float my_sqrt(float x) { return sqrtf(x); }
```

And similar specializations for the other three types. Then in `foo` just call that wrapper

```
template<typename Precision>
void foo(Precision arg) {
    my_sqrt(arg);
}
```

Comment: Correct, these are C-like functions. I'm also calling into BLAS/cuBLAS that have a billion different flavors.

Comment: @proteneer well C has no overloading so you will have to list all functions and the types for which you want to call them, see eg Nathans answer, no way around that

Comment: To be precise - I'm using C++11 that's calling *into* C functions. But I don't think that changes your answer in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to C++17, you can write template specializations calling the appropriate function:

```
template<class NumericType>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<NumericType, double>::value, void>::type foo(const NumericType number) {
  return sqrt(number);
}
```

And similar overloads as you need them.